# When to follow up for the formal contract to sign after getting the job offer via email if the job doesnt start a month from now?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I was interviewed November and it was for a job for January. Waited a month to hear back from them and I got the job offer via email on December 9. I replied and accepted and asked them to send the formal contract. But haven't heard from them since.

They already gave a start date which is Jan 4. But I know its also the holiday season so they're busy but its been a week and they still haven't sent the offer. I'm starting to get anxious.

I wanna follow up but I don't want to bug them. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

As much as it's holiday season, it's all more reason to clear the backlogs before the holidays.

Follow up with them **over phone**, so that the formal contract is sent to you. As you might have noticed already, emails are easily ignored (or prone to falling through cracks).

Jan 4th. will be right after the holidays and it's quite possible not all the departments will be fully up and running - so any pending activities that can be cleared before entering the holidays will be beneficial for both the parties here.

Comment: Phone is the best way, 
Just want to add a little thing,  contract can be waiting for you on your start date, some companies have a process of on-boarding the new hires. If this is the case, you should know where and to whom to go on your first day.

Comment: @Strader Right, company should at least send that as a response then. Either way, a response is needed.

Comment: Agreed 100%. OP should follow up now and the phone is the best medium

Comment: @strader i dont know their phone number. Theyre not a huge company so i bet they wouldnt even answer too. But i just emailed them already